# Limit of trig function as x approaches zero

Tags: calculus

What is the following limit?
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)}{x}
$$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Three things: 1) Here, you can actually enter math formatting to make things easier to read.  Please take a look at the edit I made to your question to see how. 2) Please, consider updating your question with some information about what you've tried and where you are getting stuck.  People on this site (myself included) will be much faster to help if you do!

Comment: Changing the top to $1-\cos x$ should probably be almost automatic. However, L'Hospital's Rule works fine directly. Using it we get that our limit is $\lim_{x\to 0}\cos(\pi/2-x)$, which is $0$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: $$\sin\left(\frac\pi2-x\right)=\cos x.$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  Use that $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)=\cos x$, and then multiply by $1+\cos x$ on the top and bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $1-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - x\right) = 1-\cos x=2\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}$.